# Getting a Model Foreign Key name and value?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to write a general function/utility to get the Foreign Key name and value passed it to another function as argument:

In the code below I get the FK

```
for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False):
            if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
...........

function f2 ({fk_name:value, fk_name2:value})
```

How do I get the name(owner) and the value (owner_id) ?

Comment: The value can be obtained with `getattr(self, field.attname)`.

Comment: and the name of the attribute ? (I want to passed in the f2 function)

Comment: Well `field.attname` of course, since here we use that to fetch the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` object has an attribute, `attname`, that specifies the name of the attribute holding the value of the primary key it refers to.

For your `owner`, the value of `field.attname` will here be `owner_id`, if you do not change anything.

We can define a dictionary that maps the names of `ForeignKey`s to the attributes that store the primary key like:

```
{
    field.name: field.attname
    for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False)
    if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey)
}
```

For your model, this thus will generate a dictionary:

```
{'owner': 'owner_id'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False):
    if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
        print(field.name, getattr(self, field.name, None))
```

this works

Comment: Is there a way to get the foreignkey field's `field type`?